# How to dynamically change data-theme in JQM for collapsible?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to do this action on button click, which is in the [collapsible](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/), so i do it like:

```
my_button.closest('div[data-theme="b"]').find('a.ui-btn-up-b').toggleClass('ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-up-d');
```

But unfortunately there still remains some styles which needs to be changed, but i don't know which...

Comment: try adding `.trigger('refresh')` after your code.

Comment: Show me please your exact markup.

Comment: Forgot to remove classes on hover `ui-btn-hover-b` replaced by `ui-btn-hover-d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated answer

Since the dynamic solution doesn't work for *collapsible*, here is a manual solution.

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/RLUbx/)**

Code

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
 var oldclass = 'ui-btn-up-b ui-body-b';
 var newclass = 'ui-btn-up-d ui-body-d';
 $('[data-role=collapsible]').find('a').removeClass(oldclass  + ' ui-btn-hover-b').addClass(newclass + ' ui-btn-hover-d');
 $('[data-role=collapsible]').find('.ui-collapsible-content').removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass);
});
```

---

### [Why collapsible data-theme cant be changed dynamically?](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3771)

---

**Old answer**

Unfortunately, the below dynamic solution *surprisingly* doesn't work.

Where `.selector` is the ID of the Collapsible.

```
$('button').on('click', function () {

 // change the theme
 $( ".selector" ).collapsible( "option", "theme", "a" );

 // apply new styles
 $( ".selector" ).collapsible().trigger('create');

});
```

Comment: @user1692333 i'll find out the problem. no worries.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/U8VNr/1/ please pay attention on header title after change.