# How to change the theme of collapsible set collapsed object in jquerymobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using jquery mobile
I have a collapsible set which contains three collapsible items
and want to change the item's theme from javascript code when it's expanded.
and return it to the normal theme when it's collapsed

Note: I don't want to change the whole collapsible set items them.
just the collapsed or expanded one.

Comment: can you post example of your markup? because it depends on what you have inside collapsibles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `collapsible` doesn't accept changing theme dynamically, therefore, you need to do it add/remove classes programmatically.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5jBUf/)**

**jQuery Mobile**

```
$(document).on('expand collapse', '#col1, #col2, #col3', function (e) {
 if (e.type == 'expand') {
    var oldclass = 'ui-btn-up-d ui-body-d';
    var newclass = 'ui-btn-up-e ui-body-e';
    $(this).find('a').removeClass(oldclass + ' ui-btn-hover-d').addClass(newclass + ' ui-btn-hover-e');
    $(this).find('.ui-collapsible-content').removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass);
   }
   if (e.type == 'collapse') {
    var oldclass = 'ui-btn-up-e ui-body-e';
    var newclass = 'ui-btn-up-d ui-body-d';
    $(this).find('a').removeClass(oldclass + ' ui-btn-hover-e').addClass(newclass + ' ui-btn-hover-d');
    $(this).find('.ui-collapsible-content').removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass);
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
 <div data-role="collapsible" id="col1">
     <h3>Section 1</h3>

    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>
 </div>
 <div data-role="collapsible" id="col2">
     <h3>Section 2</h3>

    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
 </div>
 <div data-role="collapsible" id="col3">
     <h3>Section 3</h3>

    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15789387/1771795

Answer (score 2):

See this fiddle:

jQuery mobile does not supports the theme changing in collapsibles directly, so you have to use manual method of removing classes and then adding new classes.

```
var oldclass = 'ui-btn-up-b ui-body-b';
    var newclass = 'ui-btn-up-d ui-body-d';
    $('[data-role=collapsible]').find('a').toggleClass(oldclass + ' ui-btn-hover-b').toggleClass(newclass + ' ui-btn-hover-d');
    $('[data-role=collapsible]').find('.ui-collapsible-content').toggleClass(oldclass).toggleClass(newclass);
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/cDmdh/

Comment: Almost like mine, but you're missing something.

Comment: Yeah.got it.I just changed the theme of collapsible header.

Comment: Also you need to bind it to `collapse`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$( ".selector" ).collapsible({ collapsed: false });
```

From: http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/