# Dynamicaly change the colapsable data-theme onclick

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

sorry if this question might look very simple but i completely stuck
here is the thing
i have a collapsible listview handled by jQuery.Mobile
i need to change the data-theme of the QUESTION button when the user clicks on one of the ANSWERs and see the answer ANSWER DETAIL
right now its changing the color around the QUESTION button not the button itself (The question which is in  tag)

here is the link to the page
http://persianrealtors.ca/SecureAccess/2.htm

any help really appriciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change data-theme in JQM for collapsible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789295/how-to-dynamically-change-data-theme-in-jqm-for-collapsible)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the class of the actual button (the  tag underneath the QuestionBlock1 element):

```
function ChangeTheme(i) {
    var $QuestionBlockC = $('#QuestionBlock' + i + ' > a');
    $QuestionBlockC.removeClass('ui-btn-up-a');
    $QuestionBlockC.addClass('ui-btn-up-d');
}
```

Here is a demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8Wyda/**